# python simple select in SQLite 3 is very slow

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I have a simple SQLite table, with ~70,000 rows, that was initialized like that:

```py
conn = sqlite3.connect(file, timeout=10, isolation_level = "DEFERRED", check_same_thread=False)
conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
conn.execute('pragma journal_mode=wal')
```

when I try to do a simple query like:

```py
import pandas as pd
# anno is a simple string  like 'username'
query = f"select image,annotation from annotations where annotation = '{anno}'"
df = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
```

It used to be very fast (~ 60ns to execute), the first time I tested it,
But after running several queries, it has become extremely slow!
the code execution can take about **9** seconds!

I added an index on the annotation column, but it did not help.

```py
conn.execute('CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS terms_index ON annotations(annotation)')
```

The query speed is slow even without using pandas. So I don't think that pandas is the problem
what can cause such a poor performance?

Comment: Have you checked the rowcount on the database? Presumably you have more code than is shown here, so the first thing is to check there are no silly mistakes and you're not running a fresh batch of inserts each time you run the code

Comment: Also, what is your system RAM usage at? Are you possibly aggregation objects in memory via something like IPython and now your memory is thrashing? It's really hard to debug this from what's shown

Comment: I don't think that I am adding new rows or something. 
The entire code is:
```
file = '/data/databases/annotations.sqlite'    
query = f"select image,annotation from annotations where annotation = '{terms}'" 
conn = None
conn = sqlite3.connect(file, timeout=10, isolation_level = "DEFERRED",  
 check_same_thread=False)   
df = pd.read_sql(query, conn)   
conn.close()    ```

Comment: row count did not change, overall ~ 170000 and the result is about 20,000 rows long

Comment: I still have about ~10GB RAM available. I am running on a VM in the cloud with ~18GB RAM.

Comment: I still don't know what happened. I ended up saving the entire table as CSV, deleting the SQLite file, and rebuild the table again.  now it is fast again. the query runs at about 50ms instead of ~10 seconds !. what happened is still a mystery to me